# Check username and password with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to verify username and password with MySQL. But it's not working. I can't find the problem. Can anybody help me fix it?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                            
    String user = jTextField1.getText();
    char[] pass = jPasswordField1.getPassword();

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN","root","");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "Select * from tbl_User Where username='" + user + "' and password='"+pass+"'";
        rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            if (user.equals(rs.getString("username")))
            {
                if (pass.equals(rs.getString("password")))
                {
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successfully");
                          main.getWindows();
                }
                          else
                                  {
                                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Login");
            }
        }
        stat.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROBLEM OCCURED !!!! ");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Users.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Actually I think it is not checking the enteries with username and password in database. am I right?

Comment: username and password are they both varchar in the database?

Comment: First and foremost; please tell me that you are not storing raw passwords in a database. Second, you need to learn about boolean logic - `&&` for example. Third, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Indeed, don't ever store passwords as pure text. An easy but safe implementation would be [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). When storing you must hash it, and when checking you must use another function to see whether a string matches the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, select by `username`, then hash the user entered password en check if it matches the hashed password in the database. I suggest something like `SHA-2`

I also suggest you write classes to handle your code, i.e a `User` class..
You also forgot to close your `ResultSet`

One more thing, use `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
Statement stat = con.createStatement();
user = user.toLowerCase();
pass = pass.toLowerCase();
String sql = "Select * from tbl_User Where LOWER(username)='" + user + "' and LOWER(password)='"+pass+"'";
rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
if(rs.next())
{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successfully");
                        main.getWindows();
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Login");

}
```

Comment: while this is correct, this is only helping OP into the grave

Comment: I did this but it keeps saying Incorrect Login . I am entering username and password correctly !

Comment: It worked , thanks all . problem was with password field. added .getText() and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for password and username match 2 times.

```
String sql = "Select * from tbl_User Where username='" + user + "' and password='"+pass+"'";
```

There you already check the password and user, First you shuld check if the password its not stored as MD5 or any other hash type

After that sql you only need to check if its returns any row like @Prabhakaran says

Answer (score 0):

Check code which is written is connecting to database, password is not there in the below code

`con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN","root","");`

Second is check the user and pass variable is getting the value from the action event.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

Code will only be used to validate the error. So you must paste the error fired by your program.

Since we don't have enough information to the problem, I will try to help you out.

1- It seems your connection variable missing the "Connection" try this :

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"DATABASENAME"?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC","USERNAME","PASSWORD");`

2 - You already made the if statement to the query in the beginning, so you don't have to start all over again with          You can simply type :
        `if (rs.next()) { 
        }

        else
        {
                                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");
            }` then carry on with the exception part

this is the code :

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN","root","");
    Statement stat = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "Select * from tbl_User Where username='" + user + "' and password='"+pass+"'";
    rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
    if (rs.next())
    {

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successfully");
                      main.getWindows();
            }
                      else
                              {
                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Login");

    }
    stat.close();
    con.close();
}
catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
{
    //e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROBLEM OCCURED !!!! ");
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Users.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

// TODO add your handling code here:
}`